Implication from Dirichlet's Theorem on arithmetic progressions
According to Dirichlet's theorem for arbitrary two coprime positive integers $a,b$ there exist infinitely many primes $p$ of the shape $a +rb$.
Question: Assume $c$ is another positive (odd ; otherwise as @lulu shows on $c=2$ one might run into troubles) integer coprime to $b$. Can we conclude from Dirichlet's theorem that there exist infinitely many primes $q$as before of shape $q=a+rb$ with additional property that $ q-1$ and $c$ coprime?
It's easy to reduce it to the case $c$ prime. But the point is how can we assure that the infinitely many primes appearing in the Dirichlet's arithmetic regression cogruent to $a$ modulo $b$ not accidentaly happen to have form $c^d+1$?

Well, you can rule out that particular form ($c^d+1$ that is) by density arguments.  The primes guaranteed by Dirichlet have a non-zero analytic density, the exponential sequence doesn't.   Not clear to me why that form is the only form you need to worry about though.

Just to say, if $a,b$ are both odd and $c=2$, then you certainly can't win, since we will have $2,|,(q-1)$ for all the primes in the progression (except possibly $1$, if $q=2$ happens to be in the progression).

@lulu: Thank you! On why my interest is focussed on that form: Just took it as "toy" model; clearly I could try to replace  the one in $q-1$ by some
positive integer $s$ coprime to $a,b$ and ans identical question for $q-s$; think this not affects you density argument.

@lulu: Add: Ok, prime $2$ is bad one, should have ruled it out to take $c$ odd

But still, how to see that the exponential sequence has zero Dirichlet density?

The sum $\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}c^{-d}$ converges.  You need a divergent series to get density.  But, again, I don't see why this exponential form is the only one you need to worry about. After all, with $c=2$ there are way more examples than just $2^d-1$.

Yes. Phrased in the language of congruences, Dirichlet's theorem says that when $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there are infinitely many primes in the residue class $a\pmod b$. Given an odd integer $c$ that is coprime to $b$, consider the residue class $2\pmod c$. The Chinese remainder theorem says that the intersection of the two residue classes $a\pmod b$ and $2\pmod c$ is some other residue class $d\pmod{bc}$, and furthermore implies that $d$ is coprime to $bc$ since $a$ is coprime to $b$ and $2$ is coprime to $c$. Now we apply Dirichet's theorem to this new residue class: we learn that there are infinitely many primes $q\equiv d\pmod{bc}$. This implies both $q\equiv a\pmod b$ and $q\equiv 2\pmod c$, the latter of which is equivalent to $q-1\equiv 1\pmod c$ and thus implies that $q-1$ is coprime to $c$ since $1$ is.

On "[...] $q-1\equiv 1\pmod c$ and thus implies that $q-1$ is coprime to $c$ since $1$ is." Is this statement in more general context true? Ie say $x,y,z$ are integers and $x \equiv  y \pmod z$. Then does it always hold that $x$ coprime to $z$ iff $y$ coprime to $z$. Your argument used $y=1$ , where it's clear. Furthermore it is clear if $z$ prime, as this would be equivalent to $x \equiv 0 \pmod z$ iff $y \equiv 0 \pmod z$. But what about arbitrary $x,y,z$? Does still holds in that generality $x$ coprime to $z$ iff $y$ coprime to $z$.

Yes, and even more: if $x\equiv y\pmod z$ then $\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(y,z)$. In fact this statement is precisely what makes the Euclidean algorithm for calculating gcds valid!

That's a nice phrasing of essense of Euklidean algorithm! I assume the most "natural" way (...maybe not the "slickest" one. suggestions welcome :) )to see it is just by writing out $x=y+az$, assuming coprimeness of $x$ and $z$ and deducing immediately a contradiction if would would assume that $y$ and $z$ are not coprime.

Like many elementary number theory proofs, there's no need for contradiction there: if $y$ and $z$ have a common divisor $d$, then $d$ also divides $y+az=x$ and so $x$ and $z$ have a common divisor. Indeed, assuming $x\equiv y\pmod z$, this is precisely the proof that the common divisors of $z$ and $z$ are the same as the common divisors of $y$ and $z$ (from which our observations about gcds and coprimality follow).
